Ajustar imagen flotante al posicionar Mouse
Tengo una lista con DATATABLE para mostrar información de solicitudes ingresadas por el usuario. En esta lista existe la columna estado solicitud, y es aquí en donde estoy intentando realizar que cuando el usuario posicione el mouse sobre el estado de la solicitud se despliegue una imagen flotante al lado izquierdo del estado. Mi problema es que no logro posicionar la imagen de manera flotante y lo que hace es agrandar el alto y ancho de la fila. Comparto mi código e imágenes que muestran mi problema.
CSS
 .list{
   display: inline-block;
 }

.list img {
   float: left;
   display: none;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
 }

.list:hover img { 
   display: block;
 }

**** FILA DATATABLE QUE MUESTRA NOMBRE ESTADO****
 return "<div class='list'>
           <span>"+data['estado']+"<img src='img.png'>
           </span>
         </div>"




Para hacer flotante la imágen usa la propiedad de position.
Para el elemento padre de la imagen como: relative
Y para el elemento hijo como: absolute.
Te quedaría algo tal que así:


.list{
   display: inline-block;
 }

.list:hover img { 
   display: block;
 }
 
 .list > span{
   position: relative;
 }
 
.list img {
   position: absolute;
   /*float: left;*/
   display: none;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   /* Ajusta acorde tus necesidades */
   right: -200px; 
   bottom: -200px;
 }
<div class='list'>
  <span>Creado
    <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQmQIOisJDMU0qTF4mka1q9fbzV2smNk1RYNA&s'>
  </span>
</div>




Muchas gracias, me funcionó según lo que necesitaba.

Estaba revisando que al ir mostrando la imagen por los diferentes estados hacia abajo, cuando llego a los últimos la imagen se pierde debido a la posición en la que se ajustó la imagen. Es posible que se ajuste la imagen en relación al estado, es decir, si el estado esta arriba la imagen se ajusta a eso, y si el estado está abajo la imagen se ajusta a esto para que se visualice correctamente.

Sí pero tendrías que añadir validaciones, lo que  usaría yo es nth-child() para identificar cuando está abajo de la tabla y cuando no.
